# How can I do a jQuery fadeOut without affecting the positioning of the other elements?

Tags: jquery

At the moment if I do something like

```
$.('#myelem').fadeOut();
```

It will successfully fade out the element but then reposition everything else on the screen.  How can I do a fade out whilst keeping all the other elements in the same place?

Comment: can you post html and css code? Hope css is affecting the position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using *fadeOut*, try *animate*:

```
$("#myelem").animate({"opacity": 0});
```

If you look at the [JQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), you will notice that *fadeOut* actually animates to "opacity: hide".  Using the straight *animate* function leaves the element displayed, just invisible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.('#myelem').animate({opacity : 0}, 600);
```

From jQuery:

> The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements.
>   Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none,
>   so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

Just animating the opacity to zero will not make it `display:none`, and will keep the element in the document flow so as not to affect other elements the same way as setting `display:none` will.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fadeTo()` method instead which animates the `opacity`:

```
$el.fadeTo('fast', 0)
```